# UITableViewController Does not Display any Data

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, parse-platform

I am working with Parse to load data onto my UITableViewController but for some reason no information even though I know that data is coming through and is being save. The problem is that it is not being show in the table viewcontroller. Here is my code.

```
import UIKit
import Parse
import ParseUI

class AvailableNearbyViewController: UITableViewController, UITableViewDataSource {

    var listOfClassFullNames: [String] = [String]()
    var totalNumberOfRows: Int = 0
    var query = PFQuery(className:"Classes")

    override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return listOfClassFullNames.count
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! UITableViewCell
        cell.textLabel?.text = self.listOfClassFullNames[indexPath.row]
        return cell

    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        query.orderByAscending("classFullName")
        query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
            (objects: [AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

            if error == nil {
                // The find succeeded.
                self.totalNumberOfRows = objects!.count
                println("totalNumberOfRows = \(self.totalNumberOfRows)")
                println("Successfully retrieved \(objects!.count) objects.")

                if let objects = objects as? [PFObject] {
                    for object in objects {
                        println(object.objectForKey("classFullName"))
                        self.listOfClassFullNames.append(object.objectForKey("classFullName") as! String)
                    }
                }

            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to reload the table view after updating the data source.

Comment: @StevenAlec welcome to StackOverflow! If an answer has helped solve your problem, please up-vote it and mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 1):

After you finish download your data from parse.com you need to reoad your table view:

```
  if error == nil {
        // The find succeeded.
        self.totalNumberOfRows = objects!.count
        println("totalNumberOfRows = \(self.totalNumberOfRows)")
        println("Successfully retrieved \(objects!.count) objects.")

        if let objects = objects as? [PFObject] {
            for object in objects {
                println(object.objectForKey("classFullName"))
                self.listOfClassFullNames.append(object.objectForKey("classFullName") as! String)
            }
        }
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }
```

Now once you finish download the new data it should start display in the table.

Because the name of the function (`findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock`) the update may be happening in another thread to be safe I update the code to send the update message to the main thread.